# Curl Redirects giving the wrong data

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am checking url status code using php curl like in the example below.

```
function statusUrl($url) {
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
 
 curl_exec($ch);
 $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 curl_close($ch);
    
 return $status;
```

}

echo statusUrl($url);

One of the websites I was testing its giving 503 (service unavailable) but when i open the link in the browser, its first showing me checking browser -- wait for 5 seconds

Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.

Redirecting…

DDoS protection by Cloudflare.
Then the website opens.
What can i do to follow the redirect and get the correct http code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be how CloudFlare DDoS protection works; the response to the first request is a 503 with content and JS that the browser then runs to prove your request is legitimate. You can see this with https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in, for example, if you keep your browser developer tools open when visiting.

Comment: Yes, exactly like the link you have provide. 
Is there something i need to do to get to the redirected page?

Comment: The only workable solution is to find another URL on the same server that you believe will give you the same information you want, but isn't behind this kind of protection. Anything else will end up in an arms race between you and CloudFlare as you attempt to reliably defeat their DDoS protection.

Comment: Will try that approach.